# Firebase Cloud Firestore how to set snapShotOptions

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am using the Node SDK for Firebase and Firestore.

When I use collection.add() I am setting the timestamp on my document using:

```
firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()
```

My issue is I am listening for changes using collection.onSnapshot and the timestamp is being returned as null because I believe the change being reported is a local change ie. the db hasn't had time to write the timestamp yet.

I believe [firebase.firestore.onSnapshotOptions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.SnapshotOptions) was added to remedy this ie. you can set to 'estimate' to have an estimated timestamp returned in snapshots for local changes - the actual timestamp being returned later in a server change.

My question is, how/where do I set this option in my app?

Answer (score 6):

I've run into the same issue and found the solution. You set the options when converting the snapshot to data. See example.

```
db.collection("cities")
    .get()
    .then(function(querySnapshot) {
        querySnapshot.docChanges().forEach(function(doc) {
            // Use the server timestamps in the .data() method
            console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data({ serverTimestamps: 'estimate' }));
        });
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
        console.log("Error getting documents: ", error);
    });
```

I will say that the documentation isn't very clear when it comes to this and have sent feedback to see if they can add an example.

Answer (score -1):

As far as I can see this type is only used in [`QuerySnapshot.docChanges()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot#docChanges). In that case, its usage should be something like this:

```
db.collection("yourcollection")
    .get()
    .then(function(querySnapshot) {
        querySnapshot.docChanges({ serverTimestamps: 'estimate' }).forEach(function(doc) {
            console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
        });
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
        console.log("Error getting documents: ", error);
    });
```

Valid values for `serverTimestamps` are: `"estimate"`, `"previous"` and `"none"` (which is the default value). See the [documentation of `SnapshotOptions. serverTimestamps`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.SnapshotOptions#~serverTimestamps) for details on their meaning.

Comment: I've tried this code and it doesn't seem to work. docChanges uses SnapshotListenOptions which only consists of includeMetadataChanges.